# Onclick com chamadas alternadas

Tags: php, html, onclick

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de implementar uma chamada alternada na função `onclick`, para que quando eu clique uma vez ele execute uma função, e quando eu clique de novo chame outra função ...

Um exemplo seria usando uma `checkbox`. Quando eu clicar a primeira vez exibe uma mensagem "Você selecionou essa opção"e faz um cálculo de adição, então se eu clicar novamente apareça uma mensagem "Você desmarcou essa opção", e faça um calculo de subtração...
A checkbox geralmente não funciona assim, mas poderia ser também por exemplo um botão simples de liga e desliga. 
Em fim, gostaria de saber se é possível realizar essa alternância usando o `onclick` e como seria.

Obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possivel, basta teres um contador de cliques e saber se a contagem está par ou impar.

Podia ser algo assim:

```js
var alternador = (function(contador) {
    return function(e) {
        contador++;
        if (contador % 2 == 0) {
            // fazer algo
            console.log(contador, 'par');
        } else {
            // fazer outra coisa
            console.log(contador, 'impar');
        }
    }
})(0);
var elemento = document.querySelector('button');
elemento.addEventListener('click', alternador);
```

```html
<button type="'button">Clica aqui!</button>
```